# How do we generate all parameter combination to form a URL

Tags: url, parameters, combinations, permutation

Suppose I have a url

```
xyz.com/param1=abc&param2=123&param3=!@#
```

Each parameter can have many values like:

```
param1 = abc, xyz, qwe 
param2 = 123, 456, 789
param3 = !@#, $%^, &*(
```

All the parameters and values will be read from an excel file. There can be n number of parameters and each may have any number of values.

I want to generate all the combinations which can be formed using all values of each parameters.

Output will be like:

```
xyz.com/param1=abc&param2=123&param3=!@#
xyz.com/param1=xyz&param2=456&param3=!@#
xyz.com/param1=qwe&param2=123&param3=!@#
xyz.com/param1=qwe&param2=456&param3=!@#
xyz.com/param1=xyz&param2=789&param3=$%^
```

...
..
and so on

Comment: Did you try something already? Any specific difficulties with your code that we could discuss? Right now your question looks more like some assignment that you would give to a software developer rather than a software developer asking his peers on StackOverflow about some programming issue.

Comment: I have already tried a program with recursion. But the problem is when a I provide a large number of parameters and large number of values specific to all parameters, it gives me memory exception. I want to find an approach without recursion by clubbing few parameters into sub buckets and getting the desired output.

I have used this approach as of now
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698008/dynamically-create-loops-to-iterate-over-a-list-of-liststrings

Answer (score 0):

besides the previous comment in your post, you need construct some nested loops.

I will assume you have a bash shell available (since you hadn't specified your wanted language).

```
for I in 'abc' 'xyz' 'qwe'
do
  for J in '123' '456' '789'
  do
    for K in '!@#' '$%^' '&*('
    do
      echo "xyz.com/param1=${I}&param2=${J}&param3=${K}"
    done
  done
done
```

Note that:

- that `'&*('` will bring you problems, since `&` is the character that you use to delimit each parameter.
- double quotes `"` around echo, will make a double quote character to make this program to fail miserably
- the same apply to `'`, `\` and some others

Comment: COrrect &*( is just an example I will use normal alphanumeric values. Also since my parameters are read from a xml file I will not be aware of the number of loops . How can I code for loops dynamically ? For that I used recursion as given in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698008/dynamically-create-loops-to-iterate-over-a-list-of-liststrings

But this recursion eats a lot of memory when the number of parameters are very large.

Comment: It seems that you have made some mistake on your recursion code and your exit condition is not beeing triggered correctly, I should suggest that you use nested loops, instead of recursion, if you are unsure about how to debug it.

Comment: there is an stantement in CS that says that "every iteration can be rewritten as an recursion, and vice versa"